# C# Cross thread event not fired

Tags: c#, events

I'm developing a telegram bot from scratch, without using libraries that aren't mine. I'm now converting my library to be event based, so i not have to hardcode everything on the library itself and i can work with more libraries together.

So far I have:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TelegramSharp.Core;
    using TelegramSharp.Core.Objects;
    using System.Threading;
    namespace Bot {
        class Program {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                BotSetup CFG = ConfigManager.LoadConfig("cfg.json");
                TelegramService TS = new TelegramService(CFG);
                TS.Init();//instantiates all classes that telegramService uses.
                TS.Parser.UpdateReceived += Parser_UpdateReceived;//this stays null. ???
                Thread Telegram = new Thread(TS.Start);
                Telegram.Start();
            }

            private static void Parser_UpdateReceived(object sender, UpdateReceivedEventArgs args) {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is marked on the comments, when i subscribe to the event, the event stays null. And my NotImplementedException is never raised.

this is how i declared the event on MessageParserClass

```
    public delegate void UpdateReceivedHandler(object sender, UpdateReceivedEventArgs args);
    public event UpdateReceivedHandler UpdateReceived;
    protected virtual void OnUpdateReceived(Message message, User bot) {
        UpdateReceived?.Invoke(this, new UpdateReceivedEventArgs(message, bot));
    }
```

and here the event is raised

```
    public void ParseMessage(Message msg, TelegramService bot) {
        parsedMessagesCount++;
        if (msg.Text != null /*&& msg.Date >= ToUnixTime(DateTime.UtcNow) - 10*/) {
            OnUpdateReceived(msg, bot.BotIdentity);
            OnTextMessageReceived(msg, bot.BotIdentity);
        }
    }
```

This happens to all the events i declared in this project (all declared and used in the same way). Is this happening because the Program class is static (and the method that subscribes too) or what? How i can fix and succesfully raise the events?

Comment: Could you explain the importance of 'cross thread' here? In this code, the event handler is going to be run on the thread that `UpdateReceived` is invoked from.

Comment: Style advice - rather than declare and mange your own delegate type, consider using `EventHandler<UpdateReceivedEventArgs>` instead. Its less code and gives you the `EventArgs` pattern for free.

Comment: @Gusdor I'm still calling the event on working thread, but event should be received on the main thread, isn't this a cross thread event?
Edit: I tried that first, but wasn't working, so i wrote the longest form and started debugging.

Comment: If you're invoking the event from a *worker* thread then any code that's subscribed to the event will be called from the worker thread. If the exception is occurring in a worker thread that would explain why you're not getting the exception in the main thread...

Comment: Checked with the debugger and no exceptions are being thrown. (I also log whatever exception is thrown so im pretty sure the program is running, is just the event that doesn't add the subscriber.) @JamJar00

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved this issue. It was related to a stupid mistake, [here you clearly see why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNMwr.png), basicalli i first execute `Init()`, instantiating all the classes that i need, then i subscribe to the event and later i start my bot, using `Start()` (that was made in an earlier version of the library), inside start i recreate the classes, so my event would have always been null.

Thanks anyway to everyone tryed to help me.

Comment: Ah, the old "spot the programming problem in the code I'm not showing you". For future reference, you may want to look into creating an [mcve] when looking for help with code problems. It means you end up showing us code that we can run ourselves and actually exhibits the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!